# How to create a function for adding records to database

Tags: c#

I want to separate the database logic from the application one, so I wrote a function for adding records:

```
public static bool AddRecordToDB(string tableName,Hashtable ht)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = CreateSqlConnection())
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from " + tableName + "where 0=1;", conn);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds, tableName);

                    //Create new record
                    DataRow newRow = ds.Tables[tableName].NewRow();
                    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in ht)
                    {
                        newRow[de.Key.ToString()] = de.Value;
                    }

                    //Add new row to dataset
                    ds.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(newRow);

                    new SqlCommandBuilder(sda);
                    sda.Update(ds, tableName);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

and use it here

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string tableName = "TestTable";
            Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
            ht.Add("FirstNumber", Double.Parse(txtFirstNum.Text));
            ht.Add("SecondNumber", Double.Parse(txtSecondNum.Text));
            ht.Add("Operator", DropDownListOp.SelectedValue);
            ht.Add("Result", Double.Parse(txtResults.Text));

            if(SQL.AddRecordToDB(tableName,ht))
            {            
                    Response.Write(@"<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("Save successful!") + "');document.location.href='WebForm1.aspx';</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode("Save Failed!") + "');document.location.href='WebForm1.aspx';</script>");
            }

        }
```

The problem is that hashtables store the data as object data type. I want to be able to have a function that will add the record and I pass in the parameters. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you have a concrete type for the record you want to add, as opposed to a `HashTable`?

Comment: The record has 4 columns (3 columns are of double type and one column is varchar datatype)

Comment: Is it represented as an instance of a type in your code?

Comment: No it isnt...you mean to create a class for the record?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should avoid weakly typed approach like this to achieve 'pseudo-decoupling'. I would definitely use a business object in this case which contains those four fields you populate the DataRow with. As long as your View code works directly with DAL it is nearly impossible to achieve high level of decoupling but anyway, working with business object in this case is much more error prone and type safe. 
Agree that while passing a Hashtable of Object values to populate a table you must be aware of data types each column represent therefore you can't pass arbitrary values to arbitrary table with single generic method assuming that they will match. Maybe you should also consider to implement a simple MVC (Model View Controller) pattern in order to really decouple the GUI from Database. There are plenty of excellent examples on the internet on this pattern.